# Remover e recolocar vogais em frase qualquer, C

Tags: c

**Contexto:**
Estou tentando desenvolver um código que seja capaz de remover todas as vogais `aeiou` de uma frase qualquer e guardar a posição que estava a vogal na frase, para que seja possível reconstruir a frase novamente usando o que foi salvo como um exemplo hipotético de "compressão/descompressão".

**Problema:**
A parte de retirar as vogais está ok, mas para coloca-las de volta está apresentando problema com determinadas palavras.

Palavras mais simples como `macaco` remove as vogais e recoloca elas normalmente, mas palavras como `papaia`, que possuem vogais seguidas, ele retorna 'papa', o que foge do necessário.

**Um exemplo do funcionamento adequado:**

```
Digite uma frase simples para compressão:warning: this program uses gets(), which is unsafe.
macaco
---------- RESULTADO DA COMPRESSÃO ----------
Sua mensagem comprimida é: mcc
Sua mensagem comprimida tem length: 3

Sua mensagem descomprimida é: [m][a][c][a][c][o]
Sua mensagem descomprimida tem length: 7

A compressão poupou: -1
-------------------------------------------
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

**Exemplo do problema mencionado:**

```
Digite uma frase simples para compressão:warning: this program uses gets(), which is unsafe.
papaia
---------- RESULTADO DA COMPRESSÃO ----------
Sua mensagem comprimida é: pp
Sua mensagem comprimida tem length: 2

Sua mensagem descomprimida é: [p][a][p][a]
Sua mensagem descomprimida tem length: 7

A compressão poupou: -1
-------------------------------------------
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

**Código:**

```
char vogaisEncontrada[100];

int main()
{
    char fraseOriginal[100],
         fraseCompactada[100],
         fraseDescompactada[100];

    int fraseOriginalLen,
        fraseFinalLen;

    printf("Digite uma frase simples para compressão:");

    gets(fraseOriginal);

    fraseOriginalLen = strlen(fraseOriginal);

    printf("---------- RESULTADO DA COMPRESSÃO ----------");

    // COMPACTA //

    int c,
        cV = 0;

    for(c = 0; c <= fraseOriginalLen; c++) {
        if(fraseOriginal[c] == 'a') {
            vogaisEncontrada[c - cV] = 'a';

            cV++;
        } else if(fraseOriginal[c] == 'e') {
            vogaisEncontrada[c - cV] = 'e';

            cV++;
        } else if(fraseOriginal[c] == 'i') {
            vogaisEncontrada[c - cV] = 'i';

            cV++;
        } else if(fraseOriginal[c] == 'o') {
            vogaisEncontrada[c - cV] = 'o';

            cV++;
        } else if(fraseOriginal[c] == 'u') {
            vogaisEncontrada[c - cV] = 'u';

            cV++;
        } else if(strlen(&fraseOriginal[c]) > 0) {
            vogaisEncontrada[c] = ' ';

            fraseCompactada[c - cV] = fraseOriginal[c];
         }
    }

    // COMPACTA //

    printf("\nSua mensagem comprimida é: %s", fraseCompactada);

    fraseFinalLen = strlen(fraseCompactada);
    printf("\nSua mensagem comprimida tem length: %d", fraseFinalLen);


    printf("\n\nSua mensagem descomprimida é: %s", fraseDescompactada);

    // DESCOMPACTA //

    int c1;

    for(c1 = 0; c1 <= fraseOriginalLen; c1++) {
        if((vogaisEncontrada[c1] == ' ') && (strlen(&fraseCompactada[c1]) > 0)) {
            printf("%c", fraseCompactada[c1]);
        } else if((strlen(&fraseCompactada[c1]) == 0) && (strlen(&vogaisEncontrada[c1]) > 0) && !(vogaisEncontrada[c1] == ' ')) {
            printf("%c", vogaisEncontrada[c1]);
        } else if((strlen(&fraseCompactada[c1]) > 0) && !(vogaisEncontrada[c1] == ' ')) {
            printf("%c", vogaisEncontrada[c1]);
            printf("%c", fraseCompactada[c1]);
        }
    }

    // DESCOMPACTA //

    fraseFinalLen = c1;
    printf("\nSua mensagem descomprimida tem length: %d\n", fraseFinalLen);

    printf("\nA compressão poupou: %d\n", (fraseOriginalLen - fraseFinalLen));

    printf("-------------------------------------------\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Acredito que a forma mais fácil de resolver seja ter dois vetores, um de vogais e outro contendo o índice dessas vogais na palavra original.

Comment: @mercador a princípio eu tentei dessa forma contudo não consegui montar a frase novamente, pois não consegui unir os dois vetores, no C é mais complicado na minha conjuntura atual..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analisei o seu código, infelizmente não consegui compreendê-lo e arrumá-lo, porém notei o seguinte:

1. `for(c = 0; c <= fraseOriginalLen; c++)` - se você tem 6 posições no vetor, você percorre de 0 até 5, então o correto é `<`.
2. `vogaisEncontrada[c - cV]` - quando você usa o `c - cV` em uma palavra com vogais seguidas, toda iteração do laço vai sempre alterar a mesma posição, com isso você acaba perdendo vogais.
3. sei que a intenção é fazer algo semelhante a compactar/descompactar, porém pelo que consegui entender do seu código (posso estar enganado), você compacta de uma maneira e tenta descompactar de outra.
4. `for(c1 = 0; c1 <= fraseOriginalLen; c1++)` -  mesma coisa do item 1.

Tentei escrever um código mais claro, veja se te ajuda:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// exibição da acentuação no console
#include <locale.h>

#define TAMANHO_VETOR 100

char vogaisEncontrada[TAMANHO_VETOR];

int main()
{
    // exibição da acentuação no console
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    // inicialização dos vetores para limpeza de sujeira
    char fraseOriginal[TAMANHO_VETOR] = { 0 },
         fraseCompactada[TAMANHO_VETOR] = { 0 },
         fraseDescompactada[TAMANHO_VETOR] = { 0 };

    int fraseOriginalLen,
        fraseFinalLen;

    printf("Digite uma frase simples para compressão:");

    // pelo que li em comentários, o gets não é recomendado
    fgets(fraseOriginal, TAMANHO_VETOR, stdin);

    // o fgets considera a quebra de linha, por isso fiz -1
    fraseOriginalLen = strlen(fraseOriginal) - 1;

    printf("---------- RESULTADO DA COMPRESSÃO ----------");

    // COMPACTA //

    int c,
        cV = 0;

    for (c = 0; c < fraseOriginalLen; c++) {
        // strchr procura um char em um string, 
        // retornando um cursor com a posição ou 
        // NULL caso não encontre
        if (strchr("aeiou", fraseOriginal[c]) != NULL) {
            vogaisEncontrada[c] = fraseOriginal[c];
            cV++;
        } else {
            vogaisEncontrada[c] = ' ';
            fraseCompactada[c - cV] = fraseOriginal[c];
        }
    }

    printf("\nSua mensagem comprimida é: %s", fraseCompactada);

    printf("\nSua mensagem comprimida tem length: %d", strlen(fraseCompactada));


    // DESCOMPACTA //

    int c1,
        // posição da consoante
        pC = 0;

    for (c1 = 0; c1 < fraseOriginalLen; c1++) {
        if (vogaisEncontrada[c1] == ' ') {
            fraseDescompactada[c1] = fraseCompactada[pC];
            pC++;
        }
        else {
            fraseDescompactada[c1] = vogaisEncontrada[c1];
        }
    }

    printf("\n\nSua mensagem descomprimida é: %s", fraseDescompactada);

    printf("\nSua mensagem descomprimida tem length: %d\n", strlen(fraseDescompactada));

    fraseFinalLen = strlen(fraseCompactada);
    printf("\nA compressão poupou: %d\n", (fraseOriginalLen - fraseFinalLen));

    printf("-------------------------------------------\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Acho que acabei me perdendo como você disse, obrigado por esclarecer esses pontos, realmente eu não os via. A função `strchr` não conhecia, irei ler mais sobre, um extremo obrigado pela sua didática.

Comment: Consegui essas informações depurando o código linha a linha, acho que isso ajuda muito! Que bom que pude ajudar!